# where can I get a XD version dojo source

Tags: dojo

WHere can I get a XD version of dojo source like the one hosted on google? What I want to do is to host dojo source from my local CDN, and my custom dojo module in my web application. Is this a good practice? or I might as well just include the dojo source in my web app, and run the custom build?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build an xd version of dojo from the source code

Here are instructions on how to do it:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/custom-builds.html

See the section on "doing xdomain builds"

In our organization (a large one), we do have a CDN version of dojo deployed on internal CDN mainly since some of our webapps are not allowed to access extranet (firewall issues).

For performance, though, a custom build gives biggest boost since it is customized to the modules you need/use - once the custom build is done, you only need to ship a single compressed js output file and a small number of supporting files

When doing your custom build, you can use the xdDojoPath and loader=xdomain if you wish to use  cross domain dojo to load your optimized js - see http://osdir.com/ml/cometd-users/2011-08/msg00050.html for some notes on this

Also see related SO question: [Dojo on a CDN vs own install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921843/dojo-on-a-cdn-vs-own-install)

Comment: thanks vijay for your quick and helpful response! What was reason for you to use an internal CDN rather custom build? I'm still debating if I want to go the internal CDN route. Since our code base still uses dojo 1.4.3, I need to deal with the async loading of my local custom dojo codes.

Comment: so we had many teams using dojo in various apps. CDN is very helpful to create quick rich prototypes using dojo widgets - no download or installation is needed. You can write an HTML with all the dojo goodness and share it with everyone and they just have to open the html in the browser (no additional installation needed) - this became very handy for us to share our UI designs with designers and for them to give us feedback

Comment: i take you've been taken care of the async loading of local modules by registering the module calling in a dojo ready callback? I think this is the major drawback of having the dojo source hosted cross domain.

Comment: we had a custom module and from what i remember all we did was to use the modulePath in djConfig and it worked well even with xdomain hosted custom module. The only thing we had to be careful was to access any dojo/dijits only *after* the modules are loaded - we ensured this by, as you mentioned, doing all dojo js processing in dojo.ready() - no inline JS that refers to any dojo code

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that with Dojo 1.7+ and the new loader, you don't have to do anything special for a cross domain build (good answer above from @Vijay Agrawal, but I think that reference guide link may need some updating for 1.7)  Just write your code to the new AMD format, use asynch:true, run the build tools to create layers, and deploy them on any server.  AMD makes use of callbacks and many of the tricks the old Dojo xd builder used to employ, but in a much simpler way.

To support older code, there is a legacy cross domain mode mentioned in the [loader docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/loader/amd.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'm using 1.4.3 now (yeah, I know). it seems like there is a lot of syntax changes in 1.7. I need to get this to work for 1.4.3 first.

Comment: thanks for the info Peller - sure sounds like a good step forward for dojo xdomain builds - they were always kinda tricky :)

Comment: @David Zhao, 1.4 code, generally, should run on 1.7.  You may be able to use the legacy cross domain mode.